# How can I make my backend accept the default information if the user didn't wish to change info?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I asked this question a while ago, but even I, explained it wrong so I'm editing it.

How can I let my backend accept the previous information if he only choose to change his email?

[image: User Only want to change the email]

Example, in this above image, the user only wants to change email and leave the rest. so the main problem is on the backend,

User.js

```
export const updateSingleUser = async (req, res) => {
    const {username, email, password,  studentid} = req.body

    const userExist = await User.findOne({username})
    const emailExist = await User.findOne({email})
    const studentidExist = await User.findOne({studentid})

    if(userExist){
        res.status(400).json("User Already Existing...")
   }else if(emailExist){
       res.status(400).json("Email Already Exists...")
   }else if(studentidExist){
       res.status(400).json("Student ID already Exists...")
   }
   else{
        if (req.body.password) {
            req.body.password = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
            req.body.password,
            'secret_key'
            ).toString();
        }
        try {
            const updateUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
                req.params.id,
                {$set: req.body},
                {new: true},
            )
            res.status(200).json(updateUser)

        } catch (error) {
            res.status(400).json("Error")
        }
    }
}
```

So what I did here before asking this question is create an if statement like this.

```
   export const updateSingleUser = async (req, res) => {
    const {username, email, password,  studentid} = req.body

    const userExist = await User.findOne({username})
    const emailExist = await User.findOne({email})
    const studentidExist = await User.findOne({studentid})

    if(email !== emailExist && studentid == studentidExist && username === userExist)
    {
        if (req.body.password) {
            req.body.password = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
            req.body.password,
            'secret_key'
            ).toString();
        }
        try {
            const updateUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
                req.params.id,
                {$set: req.body},
                {new: true},
            )
            res.status(200).json(updateUser)

        } catch (error) {
            res.status(400).json("Error")
        }
    }
    else{
        res.status(400).json("Email Already Exists")
    }
    
}
```

But when I try to run it on the postman, this thing happen
[image: Result]

I'm having a rough time what statement should I do, is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Here, in the code, you are checking for the userId, emailId, and studentId and checking if it exists. Before updating the email, it is still in the database, so it will print the email that already exists.

So, remove the following line from the code.

```
else if(emailExist){
   res.status(400).json("Email Already Exists...")
}
```

The updated code of User.js:

```
export const updateSingleUser = async (req, res) => {
const {username, email, password,  studentid} = req.body

const userExist = await User.findOne({username})
const emailExist = await User.findOne({email})
const studentidExist = await User.findOne({studentid})

if(userExist){
    res.status(400).json("User Already Existing...")
}else if(studentidExist){
   res.status(400).json("Student ID already Exists...")
}
else{
    if (req.body.password) {
        req.body.password = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(
        req.body.password,
        'secret_key'
        ).toString();
    }
    try {
        const updateUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
            req.params.id,
            {$set: req.body},
            {new: true},
        )
        res.status(200).json(updateUser)

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400).json("Error")
    }
    }
}
```